# Merge two array list with different attributes of Employee to create a new array list combining the attributes of both the arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an arrayList of EmployeeDetails object and another arrayList of EmployeeSalary object.I want to create a new ArrayList that has both the attributes of EmployeeDetails and EmployeeSalary.My EmployeeDetails class has attributes "id" and "name".My EmployeeSalary class has attributes "id" and "salary".I want an arraylist with attributes "id","name" and "salary".

EmployeeDetails Class

```
public class EmployeeDetails {

    private String id;
    private String name;
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

EmployeeSalary class

```
public class EmployeeSalary {

    private String id;
    private String sal;
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getSal() {
        return sal;
    }
    public void setSal(String sal) {
        this.sal = sal;
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you thought about to solve this problem? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, set up a map to access the salaries from the IDs:

```
Map<String, String> salaryMappings = new HashMap();
for(EmployeeSalary salary : salaries) {
    salaryMappings.put(salary.getId(), salary.getSal());
}
```

(where your salary ArrayList is named `salaries`).

Next, you need a class to store the information (note I'm not writing the accessors for sake of keeping the post short, though you should add them):

```
class EmployeeInformation {
    String id;
    String name;
    String sal;

    public EmployeeInformation(String id, String name, String sal) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.sal = sal;
    }
}
```

Finally, copy the values into a new ArrayList:

```
List<EmployeeInformation> infos = new ArrayList<EmployeeInformation>();
for(EmployeeDetails detail : details) {
    infos.add(new EmployeeInformation( details.getId(), details.getName(), salaryMappings.get(details.getId()) ));
}
```

Comment: Thank you @ZNix.It works perfectly fine. :). Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

EmployeeSalary should extend Employeedetails

```
public class EmployeeSalary extends EmployeeDetails{

private String sal;

...
```

After that, in order to merge two lists arraylist1.addAll(arraylist2) should be invoked.

Answer (score 1):

No need to use HashMap or Map. Just use java 8 lambda :)

Create EmployeeInformation.java class.

```
public class EmployeeInformation {

    String id;
    String name;
    String sal;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getSal() {
        return sal;
    }

    public void setSal(String sal) {
        this.sal = sal;
    }

    public EmployeeInformation(String id, String name, String sal) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.sal = sal;
    }
}
```

Find the full solution.

```
List<EmployeeDetails> employeeDetailsList = new ArrayList<>();

        EmployeeDetails employeeDetails1 = new EmployeeDetails();
        employeeDetails1.setId("A");
        employeeDetails1.setName("EMP1");
        employeeDetailsList.add(employeeDetails1);


        EmployeeDetails employeeDetails2 = new EmployeeDetails();
        employeeDetails2.setId("B");
        employeeDetails2.setName("EMP2");
        employeeDetailsList.add(employeeDetails2);

        List<EmployeeSalary> employeeSalariesList = new ArrayList<>();

        EmployeeSalary employeeSalary1 = new EmployeeSalary();
        employeeSalary1.setId("A");
        employeeSalary1.setSal("SAL1");
        employeeSalariesList.add(employeeSalary1);

        EmployeeSalary employeeSalary2 = new EmployeeSalary();
        employeeSalary2.setId("B");
        employeeSalary2.setSal("SAL2");
        employeeSalariesList.add(employeeSalary2);



        List<EmployeeInformation> employeeInformationList = new ArrayList<>();


        employeeDetailsList.forEach(employeeDetails -> {
            String _id = employeeDetails.getId();
            String _name = employeeDetails.getName();
            employeeSalariesList.stream().filter(employeeSalary -> employeeSalary.getId().equalsIgnoreCase(_id)).forEach(employeeSalary -> {
                EmployeeInformation employeeInformation = new EmployeeInformation(_id, _name, employeeSalary.getSal());
                employeeInformationList.add(employeeInformation);

            });

        });

        for (EmployeeInformation employeeInformation : employeeInformationList) {
            System.out.println(employeeInformation.getId() + "-" + employeeInformation.getName() + "-" + employeeInformation.getSal());
        }
```

Output ->

```
A-EMP1-SAL1
B-EMP2-SAL2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the two collections to maps of `id`->`value` and then do a secondary lookup.

The following constructs a collection of `Map<String, String>` with the keys required in your result:

```
List<EmployeeDetails> details = ...;
List<EmployeeSalary> salaries = ...;

Map<String, EmployeeDetails> detailsMap = details.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(EmployeeDetails::getId, 
            Collectors.reducing(null, (e1, e2) -> e1)));
Map<String, EmployeeSalary> salariesMap = salaries.stream()
          .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(EmployeeSalary::getId, 
            Collectors.reducing(null, (e1, e2) -> e1)));

List<Map<String, String>> summaries = detailsMap.entrySet().stream()
        .map(entry -> {
               Map<String, String> m = new HashMap<>();

    m.put("id", entry.getKey());
    m.put("name", entry.getValue().getName());
    m.put("salary", salariesMap.get(entry.getKey()).getSal());

    return m;
}).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

It's likely that you'll choose to build a separate class for the summary, having the `id`, `name`, and `salary` fields, instead of using a `Map`. But this is an idea of how to go about it.

Answer (score 0):

I think, the best solution is to create another class (e.g. `EmployeeData`) and collect all required data there. In case you do not want (or cannot) modify definitions of `EmployeeDetails` and `EmployeeSalry`.

```
class EmployeeData {

    private final String id;
    private String name;
    private String sal;

    public EmployeeData(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}

private static List<EmployeeData> merge(List<EmployeeDetails> details, List<EmployeeSalary> salaries) {
    Map<String, EmployeeData> data = new HashMap<>();
    String id;

    for (EmployeeDetails detail : details) {
        id = detail.getId();
        if (!data.containsKey(id))
            data.put(id, new EmployeeData(id));
        data.get(id).setName(detail.getName());
    }

    for (EmployeeSalary salary : salaries) {
        id = salary.getId();
        if (!data.containsKey(id))
            data.put(id, new EmployeeData(id));
        data.get(id).setSal(salary.getSal());
    }

    return new ArrayList<>(data.values());
}
```